# Converge of an inversion to a mirrorring

Tags: analysis, geometry

I want to ask something about a mirroring and a inversion in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
An inversion in a sphere with center $m$ and radius $\rho$ can be written as

$$
 v \ \longmapsto \ \frac{\rho^2}{\|v-m\|^2}\cdot(v-m) + m 
$$

The radius can be chosen in such a way that it maps the unit sphere onto itself. This is the case if the sphere in which we invert intersects the unit sphere orthogonally, from which one can derive the condition

$$\rho^2 = \|m\|^2 -1$$

[image: Illustration of the above equation]

Using that, the inversion which preserves the unit sphere can be written as

$$
 v \ \longmapsto \ \frac{\|m\|^2-1}{\|v-m\|^2}\cdot(v-m) + m 
$$

Now I choose some unit vector $n$ and I study the family of maps:

$$
v \ \longmapsto \ \frac{\lambda^2-1}{\|v - \lambda n\|^2} \cdot (v-\lambda n)
+ \lambda n \quad \text{for} \quad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}
$$

[image: Sketch for the inversions]

Now I take another map, namely the mirroring in the plane 
$\{v: \langle v,n \rangle = 0\}$, which is giving as follows, if I am not mistaken:
$$
v \ \longmapsto \ v - 2n \cdot \langle v,n\rangle
$$
I want to show that the inversion goes uniformely to the the other map in the unit ball as $\lambda$ grows. However, the analytic straight forward way is pretty cumbersome, so I hope that you can tell me if there is a better way to solve it.

If something is unclear, please tell me, so that I know I have to provide more information for this question to be answered.

Comment: I'm surprised about this $\lVert m\rVert^2-1$ in the numerator. Shouldn't that be simply $r^2$ for an arbitrary sphere, and $1$ for a unit sphere? The way I read it [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Inversion_in_higher_dimensions) agrees.

Comment: Also note that if you keep the radius fixed and only increase the length of the vector denoting the center, then you won't get a reflection in the limit but instead some transformation which maps everything to a given point at infinity. If you want reflections in the limit, you have to increase $r$ as you increase $m$, so the $\lambda^2$ in the numerator makes sense (but the $-1$ still doesn't).

Comment: I guess that this really needs a sketch, but I don't know how to add one.

Comment: I'm surprised you are talking about *two* circles now; I assumed $v$ to be a point so you'd invert a point in a circle. A sketch would certainly be useful. When you edit your post, there is a button with a picture on it which you can use to include images. If you lack electronic tools to generate an accurate illustration, a hand-drawn sketch will still be better than none.

Comment: It's just about one circle, but the reason it has the given radius, is that it should map the unit circle to utself. I'll send you a sketch

Comment: Ah! I completely missed the point that you are talking not about inversions in generic spheres or in spheres of unit radius, but instead only inversions which fix the unit sphere. The pictures help, thanks a lot! I updated your question to make things clearer, I hope you are OK with that or edit if not. Now I'll only have to consider how this new understanding affects my answer.

Comment: I just edited your post again, adding a $\lambda v$ to the right hand side. I guess that was only a mistake on your part while posting this question, but if not, take care to include that term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: This is a very long post, since I attacked this in a far more general way than the actual question warrants, due to me misunderstanding the question at first. If all you want is an answer to this question, then skip to the paragraph following the last header. If you have a more general question regarding sphere inversions, then continue reading everything.

## Describing inversions in general

At first I didn't understand your question correctly, and therefore wrote a lot of stuff which might not have been needed in hindsight, but which I'll use anyway. So in the first part of this question I'll introduce a nice framework for describing inversions in general.

### Take two more dimensions

I'd try projective Möbius geometry, a subset of Lie geometry. Try representing a sphere $c$ with center $m$ and radius $r$ using homogeneous coordinate vectors of the following form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_d\\c_{d+1}\\c_{d+2}\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\m_2\\\vdots\\m_d\\m_1^2+m_2^2+\dots+m_d^2-r^2\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

This lives in a projectivized Minkowski space $\mathbb P(\mathbb R^{d+1,1})$ but don't worry about names here. This space has an inner product which is defined as

$$\langle a,b\rangle:=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots+a_db_d
-\tfrac12 a_{d+1}b_{d+2}-\tfrac12 a_{d+2}b_{d+1}$$

This inner product will be zero iff two spheres intersect one another orthogonally. Points are simply represented as spheres of radius $0$; these are exactly the only vectors $p$ which satisfy $\langle p,p\rangle=0$ even though $p\neq 0$.

### Deduction of the formula for inversions

Now for inversions. An inversion in the unit sphere operating on points can be written as

$$
\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\m_2\\\vdots\\m_d\\\sum m_i^2\\1\end{pmatrix}\mapsto
\frac1{\sum m_i^2}
\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\m_2\\\vdots\\m_d\\1\\\sum m_i^2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since these are homogeneous coordinates, you can ignore the scalar factor infront of the vector. So you invert in the unit sphere simply by swapping the last two coordinates. I've explained this for points, but since this is a linear transformation of the coordinate vector, it will preserve incidence so it works for spheres as well.

Now how about inverting in some other sphere, namely a sphere $c$ with center $m$ and radius $r$? (So where up to now $c,m,r$ described the object which gets inverted, now it's a description of the inversion itself, so please don't get confused.) We can reduce that to the inversion in the unit sphere by combining it with translation and scaling operations. So we translate $m$ into the origin, scale by $\frac1r$, do the inversion, then scale by $r$ and translate the origin back to $m$. To keep things simply, I'll write down the case of $d=2$ dimensions, but this generalizes.

$$
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&0&m_1\\0&1&0&m_2\\2m_1&2m_2&1&m_1^2+m_2^2\\0&0&0&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
r&0&0&0\\0&r&0&0\\0&0&r^2&0\\0&0&0&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
r&0&0&0\\0&r&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&r^2
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&0&-m_1\\0&1&0&-m_2\\-2m_1&-2m_2&1&m_1^2+m_2^2\\0&0&0&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\\
=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
-2 m_{1}^{2} + r^{2} & -2 m_{1} m_{2} & m_{1} & m_{1}^{3} + m_{1} m_{2}^{2} -  m_{1} r^{2} \\
-2 m_{1} m_{2} & -2 m_{2}^{2} + r^{2} & m_{2} & m_{1}^{2} m_{2} + m_{2}^{3} -  m_{2} r^{2} \\
-2 m_{1}^{3} - 2 m_{1} m_{2}^{2} + 2 m_{1} r^{2} & -2 m_{1}^{2} m_{2} - 2 m_{2}^{3} + 2 m_{2} r^{2} & m_{1}^{2} + m_{2}^{2} & m_{1}^{4} + 2 m_{1}^{2} m_{2}^{2} + m_{2}^{4} - 2 m_{1}^{2} r^{2} - 2 m_{2}^{2} r^{2} + r^{4} \\
-2 m_{1} & -2 m_{2} & 1 & m_{1}^{2} + m_{2}^{2}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\\
=\begin{pmatrix}
- c_{1}^{2} + c_{2}^{2} -  c_{3} c_{4} & -2 c_{1} c_{2} & c_{1} c_{4} & c_{1} c_{3} \\
-2 c_{1} c_{2} & c_{1}^{2} -  c_{2}^{2} -  c_{3} c_{4} & c_{2} c_{4} & c_{2} c_{3} \\
-2 c_{1} c_{3} & -2 c_{2} c_{3} & c_{1}^{2} + c_{2}^{2} & c_{3}^{2} \\
-2 c_{1} c_{4} & -2 c_{2} c_{4} & c_{4}^{2} & c_{1}^{2} + c_{2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you write $M$ for the matrix of the inner product, i.e. $\langle a,b\rangle=a\cdot M\cdot b^T$, and also use $E$ to denote the unit matrix, then you can write this inversion matrix as

$$\langle c,c\rangle E - 2c\cdot c^T\cdot M$$

So applied to a point $p$ this gives

$$p\mapsto \left(\langle c,c\rangle E - 2c\cdot c^T\cdot M\right)p
=\langle c,c\rangle p - 2\langle c,p\rangle c$$

This form is in fact a reflection in $\mathbb R^{d+1,1}$. If you think of $c$ as a unit vector, and ignore for the moment the strange nature of this specific inner product, and instead think of the standard dot product instead, then the above would simply be a Euclidean reflection in $\mathbb R^{d+2}$.

### From inversions to reflections

Now you are considering the limit where this inversion in sphere geometry becomes a reflection. In that case, the center moves towards infinity, and the radius will become infinite as well.
All of this is nicely captured in the homogeneous sphere coordinates simply by setting $c_{d+2}=0$. This can be no ordinary point or sphere, since you can't find a representative which has a $1$ in that coordinate again. So when does a point $p$ lie on such a degenerate sphere $c$?

$$0=\langle c,p\rangle=c_1p_1+c_2p_2+\dots+c_dp_d-\frac12c_{d+1}p_{d+2}$$

So if you consider representatives with $p_{d+2}=1$, then this is simply the plane with normal vector $(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n)^T$ and if that vector has unit length then the offset is simply $\frac12c_{d+1}$. So vectors with $c_{d+2}=0$ describe planes, where the first $n$ coordinates describe the normal and the $(d+1)$-th coordinate fixes the offset in some almost-standard way. (A special case is the situation where the first $d$ coordinates are zero as well; that would be the point at infinity.)

## Application to your case

As I realize now, you are not asking for generic inversions, but only those which leave the unit sphere fixed. Hence your relation $r=\lVert m\rVert-1$. Using $m=\lambda n$ such an inversion would be denoted as

$$c=(\lambda n_1,\lambda n_2,\dots,\lambda n_d,1,1)^T$$

You can check that this is orthogonal to the unit sphere $(0,0,\dots,0,-1,1)$ by evaluating the inner product. Now to allow for $\lambda\to\infty$, let's introduce $\mu=\frac1\lambda$ and consider $\mu\to0$ instead. Dividing your vector by $\lambda$ you obtain

$$c=(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_d,\mu,\mu)^T$$

Now let's look at the inversion formula.

\begin{align*}
\langle c,c\rangle &= \lVert n\rVert^2-\mu^2 \\
\langle c,p\rangle &= \langle n,v\rangle_d-\tfrac12\mu(1+\lVert v\rVert^2) \\
p\mapsto p'=\langle c,c\rangle p - 2\langle c,p\rangle c &=
(\lVert n\rVert^2-\mu^2)p + (\mu(1+\lVert v\rVert^2)-2\langle n,v\rangle_d) c
\end{align*}

Now $p'$ is srtill a sphere vector. If $p$ is a point, then so is $p'$, so we may safely ignore the $p'_{d+1}$ coordinate which contains the radius information. We need to be aware of the last coordinate, and use that as a divisor to dehomogenize our point. So what is that last coordinate?

\begin{align*}
p'_{d+2}&=(\lVert n\rVert^2-\mu^2)1 +
(\mu(1+\lVert v\rVert)-2\langle n,v\rangle_d)\mu \\&=
\lVert n\rVert^2-2\mu\langle n,v\rangle_d+\mu^2\lVert v\rVert^2
=\lVert n-\mu v\rVert^2
\end{align*}

### Back to non-projective view

So back in the world of plain $\mathbb R^d$, this is the formula you'd get:

$$v\mapsto\frac{\lVert n\rVert^2-\mu^2}{\lVert n-\mu v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{\mu(1+\lVert v\rVert^2)-2\langle n,v\rangle}{\lVert n-\mu v\rVert^2}n
\tag{1}$$

If you assume $\mu=1$, then you should be back in the case of the simple sphere inversion. So let's check that:

$$v\mapsto\frac{\lVert n\rVert^2-1}{\lVert n-v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{1-\lVert n\rVert^2+\lVert n\rVert^2-2\langle n,v\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2}
{\lVert n-v\rVert^2}n=
\frac{\lVert n\rVert^2-1}{\lVert n-v\rVert^2}(v-n)+
\frac{\lVert n-v\rVert^2}{\lVert n-v\rVert^2}n$$

On the other hand, for $\mu=0$ you get reflection in the plane:

$$v\mapsto\frac{\lVert n\rVert^2}{\lVert n\rVert^2}v+
\frac{-2\langle n,v\rangle}{\lVert n\rVert^2}n$$

Everything in between is covered by values of $\mu$ between these two extremes.

If you want to translate back from $\mu$ to $\lambda$ and also assume $\lVert n\rVert=1$, then you expand all fractions by $\lambda^2$ and get

$$v\mapsto\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{1+\lVert v\rVert^2-2\langle \lambda n,v\rangle}
{\lVert\lambda n-v\rVert^2}\lambda n
=\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}(v-\lambda n)+\lambda n
\tag{2}$$

It seems as if this would be the correct formula to describe the family of inversions you mentioned.

### The other way round

So now we've come full circle: starting from general inversions, we are back at the formula from your question. And in between we had a step where things worked out nicely. So let's try to get there on a more direct, less roundabout way.

\begin{align*}
v&\mapsto\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}(v-\lambda n)+\lambda n
\\&=\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2-(\lambda^2-1)}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}\lambda n
\\&=\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{\lVert \lambda n\rVert^2-2\langle \lambda n,v\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2-\lambda^2+1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}\lambda n
\\&=\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{-2\langle\lambda n,v\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2+1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}\lambda n
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\phantom=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left(
\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}v+
\frac{-2\langle\lambda n,v\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2+1}{\lVert \lambda n-v\rVert^2}
\lambda n\right)
\\&=
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left(
\frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2\lVert n\rVert^2}v+
\frac{-2\lambda^2\langle n,v\rangle}{\lambda^2\lVert n\rVert^2}n\right)
\\&=
v-2\langle n,v\rangle n
\end{align*}

So the key to this solution is really the binomial equation

$$\lVert a-b\rVert^2=\langle a-b,a-b\rangle=
\langle a,a\rangle-\langle a,b\rangle-\langle b,a\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle
=\lVert a\rVert^2-2\langle a,b\rangle+\lVert b\rVert^2$$

Comment: Why should I introduce *two* new coordinates? I only need one to express the radius, and $n$ for the center, so I'd say that that is good enough.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin: Taking one more coordinate than you need is a general idea behind homogeneous coordinates. It helps you avoid divisions, and by doing so, it allows you to introduce objects which are infinitely far away and to avoid corner cases. But I've now concluded my answer with a paragraph which avoids all the previous deductions and simply gets at where I think the core of this question actually lies. I'll still keep all the rest in place, since this is how I obtained the result and since it might be useful in the future for some other reader.

Comment: Are you sure dat the inner product between two spheres equals zero when they are cutting perpindicularily? What I get as that they have the same center.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin: Yes I'm sure. You get exactly the Pythagorean situation from your picture. For example for $d=2$: $$-2\langle a,b\rangle = -2x_ax_b-2y_ay_b+x_a^2+y_a^2-r_a^2+x_b^2+y_b^2-r_b^2=(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2-r_a^2-r_b^2$$

Comment: I accepted you answer only because of the last part of it. I have few time to sift trough the good-looking ideas above As soon as I will have more time to do so, I hope that you can help me to study it carefully. Thank you for this nice answer.